# Why does Tor Browser make mds_stores use so much CPU on macOS?

Tags: mac

Everytime I actively use Tor Browser, the mds_stores process in the Activity Monitor uses 95-100% of the CPU. I have to wait about ten minutes for mds_stores to return to normal CPU usage (< 0.5%) after I quit Tor Browser. How can I prevent mds_stores from using so much CPU when Tor Browser is open? No other programs on my system cause this issue. I am running macOS 10.14.5.

Comment: How did you install the Tor Browser? It seems that the ‘mds_stores’ process is related to Spotlight, so maybe Spotlight is indexing all of the Tor Browser’s program files. I could see this happening if you installed the Tor Browser into your home directory.

Comment: When I installed it, I dragged it to the Applications folder. I am wondering if Tor Browser is constantly creating/modifying any files that are saved on my system.